# Why is my 1000px wide image in Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 not filling the full large-12 column?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 with vanilla CSS.

My image of 1000pxx430px is not taking up the 100% width per this screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkp1w4pz3e4xrgt/Screenshot%202016-05-24%2010.57.33.png?dl=0

I thought it was established per my question [In Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 to what size(s) do I resize JPEGs such as 5472x3080 to take up the whole 12 columns or less using Interchange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355593/in-zurb-foundation-5-5-3-to-what-sizes-do-i-resize-jpegs-such-as-5472x3080-to) that for Foundation 5.5.3 using a 12-column set up the width equals 1000px thus to cover the full 12 columns you'd want to size an image to 1000px wide ?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or a code snippet here on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your row class is width 1200px and your image is 1000px. 
Try with this:

```
<img src="/img/IMG_4039_1000x430.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

and it will works as you expect

Comment: yes thank you I just realized that this is caused by the CSS which has http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/reXMaG                                                        .row {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

Comment: You're right.  In order to have the footer look good a while back I had copied code that include CSS which set the row to 1200px per this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqgjoP. The problem is now that if I delete this line, it messes up my entire footer and with my limited CSS skills I haven't been able to fix it... In the codepen the issue does not show but in the site it does. The view goes from this https://www.dropbox.com/s/hveb5wma7c774sr/Screenshot%202016-05-24%2014.39.04.png?dl=0 to this https://www.dropbox.com/s/fyhaq3toayz9q27/Screenshot%202016-05-24%2014.39.59.png?dl=0

Comment: or is it better that I leave my row as 1200px instead of 1000px...? Is there anything else I should change in the original Foundation.css to avoid issues using 1200px rows ?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add the class `.small-12` to the image and it will take 100% available width.

```
<img src="/img/IMG_4039_1000x430.jpg" class="small-12">
```